# React: props not updating correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to implement a social media website that uses react and redux.

Essentially what I am doing is storing them as separate components and then I am doing some other stuff.

However, the weird thing is that when the action gets completed, when I print out `this`, it shows the correct state that I want. However, if I try to access the props in an arrow function, it does not update the state.

**Using `this` directly**

```
socketSend = () => {
    console.log(this);
  };
```

the props displays:

```
{
  "isLoading": false,
  "posts": [
    {
      "id": 262,
      "likes": [],
      "comments": [],
      "author": "root",
      "content": "fef",
      "date": "2021-01-04T01:16:36.930345Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 261,
      "likes": [],
      "comments": [],
      "author": "root",
      "content": "dd",
      "date": "2021-01-04T01:08:33.835076Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 260,
      "likes": [],
      "comments": [],
      "author": "root",
      "content": "fef",
      "date": "2021-01-04T01:07:26.989194Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 259,
      "likes": [],
      "comments": [],
      "author": "root",
      "content": "fefef",
      "date": "2021-01-04T01:02:52.863209Z"
    }
  ],
  "user": {
    "id": 1,
    ....
    "last_login": "2021-01-04T00:25:57.172668Z",
    "is_superuser": true,
    "username": "root",
    "first_name": "Root",
    "last_name": "Admin",
    "is_active": true,
    "is_admin": false,
    "verified": false,
    "is_staff": true,
    "groups": [],
    "user_permissions": [],
    "blocked_users": [],
    "friends": []
  },
  "post": {
    "id": 262,
    "likes": [],
    "comments": [],
    "author": "root",
    "content": "fef",
    "date": "2021-01-04T01:16:36.930345Z"
  }
}
```

which is what I want. However, if try to access the post object directly, ie `console.log(this.props.post)`, it returns an empty object (`{}`)

**NOTE** the `post` is supposed to be updated only when the compose button gets clicked.

Here is the relevant code:

**Feed.js**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import Preloader from "../../Preloaders/Preloader";
import AlbumsHelpModal from "./AlbumsHelpModal";
import AlbumsModal from "./AlbumsModal";
import ComposeCard from "./ComposeCard";
import CreateGroupModal from "./CreateGroupModal";
import FeedPost from "./FeedPost";
import NoStreamModal from "./NoStreamModal";
import ShareModal from "./ShareModal";
import VideosHelpModal from "./VideosHelpModal";
import VideosModal from "./VideosModal";
import BirthdayWidget from "./Widgets/BirthdayWidget";
import StoresWidget from "./Widgets/StoresWidget";
import SuggestedFriendsWidget from "./Widgets/SuggestedFriendsWidget";
import { init, initPageloader } from "./actions";
import { ChevronRight, HelpCircle } from "react-feather";
import { initSidebar } from "./actions/feedActions";
import { getPosts } from "../../../actions/posting";
import SocketInstance from "../../../websocket/socket";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { post } from "jquery";

export class Feed extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    isLoading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    getPosts: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    posts: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    post: PropTypes.object,
  };
  // constructor() {
  //   this.initializeSocket();
  // }

  state = {
    posts: [],
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.initializeSocket();
  }

  initializeSocket() {
    this.socketConnection(() => {
      this.props.getPosts();
    });
    SocketInstance.connect("");
  }

  socketConnection(callback) {
    const component = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
      if (SocketInstance.state() === 1) {
        console.log("Connection is made");
        callback();
        return;
      } else {
        console.log("wait for connection...");
        component.socketConnection(callback);
      }
    }, 1000);
  }

  socketSend = () => {
    console.log(this.props.post);
    // SocketInstance.send();
  };

  render() {
    const { isLoading } = this.props;
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <div id="main-feed" className="container">
          <Preloader />
          <div
            id="activity-feed"
            className={`view-wrap true-dom ${isLoading ? "is-hidden" : ""}`}
          >
            <div className="columns">
              <div class="column is-3 is-hidden-mobile">
                <div className="feed-menu-v1">
                  <ul className="main-menu">
                    <li className="is-active">
                      <a>
                        <i data-feather="activity"></i>
                        <span>Feed</span>
                        <span className="close-icon">
                          <ChevronRight />
                        </span>
                      </a>
                      <ul className="submenu">
                        <li className="is-subactive">
                          <a>
                            Trending <span className="tag">4</span>
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a>Popular</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a>Following</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a>
                        <HelpCircle />
                        <span>Questions</span>
                        <span className="close-icon">
                          <ChevronRight />
                        </span>
                      </a>
                      <ul className="submenu">
                        <li>
                          <a>Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a>My Questions</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a>Popular</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a>
                        <i data-feather="youtube"></i>
                        <span>Videos</span>
                        <span className="close-icon">
                          <ChevronRight />
                        </span>
                      </a>
                      <ul className="submenu">
                        <li>
                          <a>
                            Home<span className="tag">7</span>
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a>Suggested</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a>My Channel</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a>
                        <i data-feather="music"></i>
                        <span>Music</span>
                        <span className="close-icon">
                          <ChevronRight />
                        </span>
                      </a>
                      <ul className="submenu">
                        <li>
                          <a>My Products</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a>
                            Trending<span className="tag">6</span>
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a>Popular</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>{" "}
              <div className="column is-6">
                <ComposeCard clicked={this.socketSend} />
                {/* <FeedPost />
                <FeedPost />
                <FeedPost /> */}
                {this.props.posts.map((post) => (
                  <FeedPost
                    key={post.id}
                    likes={post.likes}
                    comments={post.comments}
                    date={post.date}
                    id={post.id}
                    socket={this.socketSend}
                    author={post.author}
                  >
                    {post.content}
                  </FeedPost>
                ))}
              </div>
              <div class="column is-3">
                <StoresWidget />
                <BirthdayWidget />
                <SuggestedFriendsWidget />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <CreateGroupModal />
        <AlbumsHelpModal />
        <AlbumsModal />
        <VideosHelpModal />
        <VideosModal />
        <ShareModal />
        <NoStreamModal />
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isLoading: state.auth.loading,
  posts: state.posting.posts,
  user: state.auth.user,
  post: state.posting.post,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getPosts })(Feed);
```

**ComposeCard.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Edit3,
  Image,
  Video,
  X,
  Camera,
  Search,
  MapPin,
  Link2,
  Tag,
  MoreHorizontal,
  MoreVertical,
} from "react-feather";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {
  openPublishWindow,
  closePublishWindow,
  openExtendedOptions,
} from "../../../actions/feed";
import { createPost } from "../../../actions/posting";
import SocketInstance from "../../../websocket/socket";

const initialState = {
  content: "",
  publishDisabled: true,
  composeFriends: false,
  composeSearch: false,
  showTagSub: false,
};

export class ComposeCard extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    openPublishWindow: PropTypes.func,
    closePublishWindow: PropTypes.func,
    opened: PropTypes.bool,
    extendFormShow: PropTypes.bool,
    openExtendedOptions: PropTypes.func,
    createPost: PropTypes.func,
  };

  state = {
    content: "",
    publishDisabled: true,
    composeFriends: false,
    composeSearch: false,
    showTagSub: false,
  };

  handleChange = (input) => (e) => {
    let val = e.target.value.trim();
    // console.log(e.target.value);
    // TODO: Disallow whitespace (trailing)
    if (val.length >= 1) {
      this.setState({
        publishDisabled: false,
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        publishDisabled: true,
      });
    }
    this.setState({ [input]: e.target.value });
  };

  submit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { content } = this.state;
    const body = { content };
    this.props.createPost(body);
    // clear the state
    this.setState({ ...initialState });
    this.props.closePublishWindow();

    // console.log(this.props.post);

    this.props.clicked();
  };

  closeForm = () => {
    const { extendFormShow } = this.props;
    this.props.closePublishWindow();
    if (extendFormShow) {
      this.props.openExtendedOptions();
    }
  };

  expandComposeFriends = () => {
    this.setState({
      composeFriends: true,
    });
  };

  toggleComposeSearch = () => {
    this.setState({
      composeSearch: !this.state.composeSearch,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { opened, openPublishWindow, extendFormShow } = this.props;
    const {
      publishDisabled,
      composeFriends,
      composeSearch,
      showTagSub,
      showActivities,
      content,
      shoWMoodSub,
      showLocationSub,
      showURLSub,
      showGIFSub,
    } = this.state;
    return (
      <div
        id="compose-card"
        class={`card is-new-content ${opened ? "is-highlighted" : ""}`}
      >
        {/* <!-- Top tabs --> */}
        <div class="tabs-wrapper">
          <div class="tabs is-boxed is-fullwidth">
            <ul>
              <li class="is-active">
                <a>
                  <span class="icon is-small">
                    <Edit3 />
                  </span>
                  <span>Publish</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a class="modal-trigger" data-modal="albums-help-modal">
                  <span class="icon is-small">
                    <Image />
                  </span>
                  <span>Albums</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a class="modal-trigger" data-modal="videos-help-modal">
                  <span class="icon is-small">
                    <Video />
                  </span>
                  <span>Video</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              {/* <!-- Close X button --> */}
              <li class="close-wrap">
                <span class="close-publish" onClick={this.closeForm}>
                  <X />
                </span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>

          {/* <!-- Tab content --> */}
          <form class="tab-content" onSubmit={this.submit}>
            {/* <!-- Compose form --> */}
            <div class="compose">
              <div class="compose-form">
                <img
                  src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300"
                  data-demo-src="assets/img/avatars/jenna.png"
                  alt=""
                />
                <div class="control">
                  <textarea
                    id="content"
                    class="textarea"
                    onChange={this.handleChange("content")}
                    rows="3"
                    placeholder="Write something about you..."
                    onClick={openPublishWindow}
                    value={content}
                  ></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div id="feed-upload" class="feed-upload"></div>

              <div id="options-summary" class="options-summary"></div>
            </div>

            <div
              id="basic-options"
              class={`compose-options ${extendFormShow ? "is-hidden" : ""}`}
            >
              {/* <!-- Upload action --> */}
              <div class="compose-option">
                <Camera />
                <span>Media</span>
                <input
                  id="feed-upload-input-2"
                  type="file"
                  type="file"
                  accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg"
                  onchange="readURL(this)"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            {/* <!-- Footer buttons --> */}
            <div class="more-wrap">
              {/* <!-- View more button --> */}

              {/* <!-- Publish button --> */}
              <button
                id="publish-button"
                type="submit"
                class={`button is-solid accent-button is-fullwidth ${
                  !publishDisabled ? "" : "is-disabled"
                }`}
              >
                Publish
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  opened: state.feed.opened,
  extendFormShow: state.feed.extendFormShow,
  post: state.posting.post,
  posts: state.posting.posts,
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  openPublishWindow,
  closePublishWindow,
  openExtendedOptions,
  createPost,
})(ComposeCard);
```

Comment: Please redact or alter any sensitive info that may exist in your code snippets, I see a "password" hash and email address (even if it's test data, it's not a good idea to post publicly).

Also is the empty object not expected if it's not meant to be populated until after Compose gets clicked?

Comment: Yes it is. However, the screenshot of the props after it gets clicked.